# Run Android Studio Emulator on Core 2 Duo 10.11.6 Mac OS

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Any way to run the Android Studio emulator (AVD) on a Core2 Duo (2008) Mac OSX El capitan?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

After three months of experimenting I finally got one to work by selecting Marshmallow ARM EABA v7a in Other Images tab in Android Studio's Virtual Device Configuration.

`Tools` > `Android` > `AVD Manager`> `+ Create Virtual Device`> `Choose Device` > `Next` > `Other Images`

[image: Marshmallow ARM EABA v7a]

Comment: is it running smoothly or you got lag on your old macbook c2d? please answer I need buy one for my cousin

Comment: Yeah, works fine for me. Have only tried it on simple apps though.

Comment: I'm on El Capitan 10.11.6 with 2.53 Ghz C2D and 8GB 1067 Mhz DDR3

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very helpfull. Why you not upgrade to Sierra?

Comment: Now you mention it, I don't know. I thought I had! :/ Give the answer an upvote if it works for you and your cuz. Will be interesting to see if it was just me or not.

Comment: What would be the hardware setup for the emulator on a C2D 2,4 and 4GB 1067 DDR3? Now, with a Nexus 4 standard setup , Marshmallow with google apis, the boot takes 5-6 min and then, on a Welcome Screen it fails and freezes the emulator.

Comment: If you've selected ARMEABA v7 and tried all the versions then just go through all of the other answers to similar questions. Keep a note of what you've tried though, there are so many answers out there.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to run a system image something other than x86; the armeabi-v7a boots up to a usable instance.